# SFML drawing elements of vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, drawing, sfml, dereference

here is the structure of my program:

```
class Game
{
public:
    unsigned int progressFlags;

    sf::RenderWindow appWindow;
    Screen* currentScreen;

    Game(const unsigned int& width, const unsigned int& height, 
         const unsigned int& bitsPerPixel, const std::string& windowName);
   ~Game();

    void drawScreen();
};
```

Game contains a Screen which is defined as:

```
class Screen
{
public:
    std::vector<sf::Drawable*> sceneElements;
    sf::Sprite backgroundSprite;
    Screen();
    virtual ~Screen();
protected:
    sf::Texture backgroundTexture;  
};
```

Elements of std::vector sceneElements are collected from screens like this:

```
sceneElements.push_back(&backgroundSprite);
```

At last, I am trying to draw all my graphic objects using a simple method:

```
void Game::drawScreen()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < currentScreen->sceneElements.size(); i++)
        appWindow.draw(*currentScreen->sceneElements(i));
}
```

But appWindow.draw() fails. I think it is something about dereferencing pointers (some basic c++ knowledge I cant just remember), but I don't know how to fix it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `sceneElements(i)` how does that compile?

Comment: You're right! Too much matlab coding for me lately ... Damn me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just derive your custom classes from `sf::Drawable` (and potentially `sf::Transformable`). This way drawing hierarchically is very easy and basically done by SFML. The following snippets are written from memory; there might be typos. :)

You'll just have to subclass your `Screen` class:

```
class Screen : public sf::Drawable
{
public:
    std::vector<sf::Drawable*> sceneElements;
    sf::Sprite backgroundSprite;
    Screen();
    virtual ~Screen();
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &rt, sf::RenderStates states) const;
protected:
    sf::Texture backgroundTexture;  
};
```

Inside `draw()` you'd just iterate over all your elements (similar to the way you do already):

```
void draw(sf::RenderTarget &rt, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    for (const auto &e : sceneElements)
        rt.draw(*e, states);
}
```

Here we're dereferencing once to get from a pointer back to the object, which is then passed by reference (where inheritance does the rest).

`Game::drawScreen()` becomes more simple as well:

```
void Game::drawScreen()
{
    appWindow.draw(*currentScreen);
}
```

Once again, derefrencing once to go from the pointer to the actual object (passed by reference).

Also note that your original design violates encapuslation, by `Game` having to know how to work with stuff that's inside your `Scene`. So if you change things inside `Scene`, you'll have to adjust `Game` accordingly. Using inheritance, you're avoiding this issue.